# Zprofile not found in Mac OS Terminal

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, zsh

I have a new mac that I have been setting up with homebrew, git, node, vs code etc.  I noticed that some applications were somehow being installed on bash terminal instead of zsh terminal.  Even though I was able to fix that, I now have an error message of

```
/Users/*****/.zprofile:1: = not found
```

I tried to create a z profile using

```
touch ~/.zprofile
```

How can I fix this error message?

Comment: What's the first line of that file? The error message means something went wrong there.

Comment: The first line gives last login time date.  The second line is the error message and the third line is the regular prompt

Comment: That sounds like the output to the terminal. Could you add the `/Users/*****/.zprofile` file to the question? You can put it inside `\`\`\`` so the formatting works correctly.

Comment: The error message does **not** say, that `.zprofile` is not found. it says that the command `=` is not found. I would have a look at the first line of your `.zprofile`.